# Opacity transition (triggered by an extra class) doesn't work backwards

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transitions

I'm firing a transition with an extra class (`.opened`) with jQuery.

```
.box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: opacity 1.3s ease;
}

.box.opened {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

The transition is smooth when the jQuery adds the `.opened` class, but not when jQuery removes it.

Should I use `animate()` or is it possible to get the expected result with CSS?

I think it's because of the `visibility` property, but why doesn't work it backwards?

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k5c53w2s/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is because only the `opacity` is being transitioned whereas the `visibility` is not and so the element disappears immediately. Because of this immediate disappearance, `opacity` transition is not visible. Transition the `visibility` also like in below snippet.

```
.box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: opacity 1.3s ease, visibility 1.3s ease;
}

.box.opened {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.trigger').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.box').toggleClass('opened');
  });
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity 1.3s ease, visibility 1.3s ease;
}
.box.opened {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="" class="trigger">Trigger</a>

<div class="box"></div>
```

**Note:** You don't really need to change `visibility` because it almost does the same thing as what is done by `opacity: 0`. Hence you can do away with the `visibility` property change.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.trigger').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.box').toggleClass('opened');
  });
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1.3s ease;
}
.box.opened {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="" class="trigger">Trigger</a>

<div class="box"></div>
```

But retaining `visibility` property change and doing away with the `opacity` change will not produce the same output (like seen in the below snippet).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.trigger').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.box').toggleClass('opened');
  });
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: visibility 1.3s ease;
}
.box.opened {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="" class="trigger">Trigger</a>

<div class="box"></div>
```

You can find the **list of properties that can be transitioned or animated** [here in the specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-properties).

Comment: Thank you @Harry. I didn't know that it's possible to use visibilty in the transition propery.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative without using jQuery (as in **pure CSS**). It uses the :target pseudo-class to toggle between an ON and an OFF state.

It also shows how to use an icon-font with menu/close button.

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons");

#box                        { width: 200px; }
#box a                      { width: 100%; position: relative; text-decoration: none }

.menu__content              { width: 100%; height: 200px; padding: 8px; opacity: 0;
                              background: rgba(255,0,0,.3); transition: opacity 0.5s ease }

#box        .menu__open     { display: block } /* initial state */
#box:target .menu__open     { display: none  } /* hidden when __content visible */
#box        .menu__close    { display: none  } /* initial state, inverse of __open */
#box:target .menu__close    { display: block } /* hidden when __content invisible */
#box        .menu__content  { opacity: 0;    } /* __close state */
#box:target .menu__content  { opacity: 1; position: relative; } /* __open state */
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <a   class="menu__open material-icons"  href="#box">menu</a>
  <a   class="menu__close material-icons" href="#"   >close</a>
  <div class="menu__content">Hello. This is some stuff inside a nice red box.</div>
</div>
```